# Display a UIImage in landscape mode even if landscape is not supported

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, orientation

Is there a way in iOS to automatically switch the device in `landscape` mode even if i do not support `landscape`(deactivated in project settings)?

I have some images. If the user taps one of the images, the image is presented in fullscreen with the content mode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` to keep the aspect ratio. Now all my images are wider than heigh, so i thought it would be better if the device switches to landscape mode when the images is presented fullscreen.

Is this possible if i've deactivated the `landscape` mode or is there a workaround, like rotating the image and navigation bar by 90 degree or something?

Comment: check out my answer in this it is similar to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116967/youtube-video-directly-not-playing-to-landscape-mode-ios-7/25119235#25119235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id) UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```